# arithmetic operation on alias of column of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query  which fetch the data like this and I wanted to calculate the opening and maindata I have formula for then which is       **( CurrentEmp + Empjoined - EmpLeft ) as opening** and **((EmpLeft*100)/((CurrentEmp+opening)/2)) as maindata** respectively I have written it in query but I gets the error saying invalid column name .

```
month      year   CurrentEmp     join    leftemp
January    2021          10     2       1
February   2021          15     3       2
March      2021          20     5       2
```

and the output that I expect is

```
 month      year   CurrentEmp     join    leftemp   opening
January    2021          10     2       1         11
February   2021          15     3       2         16
March      2021          20     5       2         23
```

I have written the below code

```
with t0(n) as ( select n from ( values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(n)),ns as(select row_number() 
over(order by t1.n) - 1 n from t0 t1, t0 t2, t0 t3),calendar as (
select top(12) DATEADD(month, n, '2021-01-01' ) dt , DATEADD(month, n , '2021-01-31')dd from ns order by n) select cast(DATENAME(month, dt) as nvarchar(max)) AS month,cast(DATENAME(YEAR, dt) as nvarchar(max))AS Year,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeDetail e left join Separation s on e.Id = s.EmployeeId 
WHERE (e.CompanyId=1 and e.DateOfJoining <calendar.dt and  e.EmpStatus = 1) or(s.CompanyId = 1 and e.DateOfJoining <calendar.dt and s.LastWorkingDate >= calendar.dt)) AS CurrentEmp,
(select count(*)  from EmployeeDetail where DateOfJoining >=calendar.dt  And DateOfJoining<=calendar.dd and CompanyId = 1) as Empjoined,
(select count(*) from Separation where LastWorkingDate >= calendar.dt  and LastWorkingDate < =calendar.dd and CompanyId =1) as EmpLeft,
(CurrentEmp+Empjoined-EmpLeft) as opening , cast (((EmpLeft*100)/((CurrentEmp+opening)/2)) as decimal(10,2)) as maindata
from calendar order by dt
```

Comment: Please don't [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74950199/arithmetic-operation-on-columns) and repost questions. Also, why go back to that unreadable formatting...? What do you have against whitespace and linebreaks?

Comment: This code is unreadable and I am not willing to read it.

Comment: It seems that the OP has an aversion or allergy to line breaks and whitespace, @OlivierJacot-Descombes , as they've had their code "nicely formatted" for them a few times, and yet they continue to provide poorly formatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alias in the current select statement cannot be used as a variable within that same select statement.

You'll need to either:

**Repeat the calculation:**

```
(CurrentEmp+Empjoined-EmpLeft) as opening, 
-- NOTE: opening IS REPLACED BY SAME CALC: (CurrentEmp+Empjoined-EmpLeft)
cast (((EmpLeft*100) /
     ((CurrentEmp+(CurrentEmp+Empjoined-EmpLeft))/2)) 
     as decimal(10,2)) as maindata
```

**Or, move the primary calculation of `opening` to a sub-query and join on that.**

But, given the simplicity and low overhead of the calculation, I'd just repeat the calculation.

Comment: Sir I am not able to understand repeat the calculation where should I but I did understand the reason of error thankyou please tell me where should I write or how should I write it to get output cause if I try to create another select query up of with Claus i gets error so I didn't tried that how should I do this and sorry for wrong formatting as I am new here I will take that and when asking next time will not do same mistake please let me know the solution

Comment: The code was in my answer.  I have edited with a `NOTE` to clarify.